# Error Message when Opening a CSV File in R

Tags: r, csv

I attempted opening a csv file in R using R studio but got this warning message:

In readLines("persons.csv") : incomplete final line found on 'persons.csv'

Please what is wrong with the file, and how can I fix it?

Comment: There can be multiple reasons: do you have cells with `#`? (Excel very often flags content it cannot process in this way!) If so, this is interpreted as a comment character and the cell in which it occurs is disregarded, which leads to one cell missing. Set `comment.char = ""`to have the `#` read-in as a normal character. Other wise, you can try `fill = TRUE`. If even that fails, do have a hard look at the data in EXCEL - maybe you can eyeball the irregularity! Finally, check out `?readLines`for additional arguments

Answer (score 2):

You can likely ignore this as it probably still worked.  Here is an example without a final newline which gives that warning and another one which has the final newline which does not give the warning.  Both worked.

```
cat("a,b\n1,2", file = "test1.csv")
read.csv("test1.csv")
##   a b
## 1 1 2
## Warning message:
## In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
##   incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'test1.csv'

cat("a,b\n1,2\n", file = "test2.csv")
read.csv("test2.csv")
##   a b
## 1 1 2
```

To address this try one of these:

1. Just ignore it as it probably worked.
2. Bring the file into a text editor and write it out again. That often eliminates the warning.
3. Use readr::read_csv.  The indicated argument eliminates many messages that are otherwise output by that command.

   ```
    library(readr)
    read_csv("test1.csv", show_col_types = FALSE)
    ## # A tibble: 1 x 2
    ##       a     b
    ##   <dbl> <dbl>
    ## 1     1     2
   ```
4. Use data.table::fread.  It won't give that message.

   ```
    library(data.table)
    fread("test1.csv", data.table = FALSE)
    ##   a b
    ## 1 1 2
   ```
5. From the Windows cmd line use this (note dot)

   ```
    echo. >> test1.csv
   ```

   or under bash (no dot)

   ```
    echo >> test.csv
   ```